# Link component just changes URL , view remains the same

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am working on a React project where I have created a AlertsTable component which renders a paginated table with a PaginatedButton component that has links to URLs with different pages for table. But those links only change URL in browser URL bar but views remain the same until I manually hit reload button of browser. I searched up a bit, one solution was that Link component in Pagina tedButton  component should be between Router component. Plus, it was also suggested that only one Router should be there in whole App so does it mean i would then have to remove Router from App.js? Which I am sure would make matters worse? I have also used the withRouter as per suggestion to get query parameter in AlertsTable component, i have got query parameter value now but view is not being updated.

I have removed the original API server URL due to obvious reasons so code sandbox doesn't display anything, but once i replaced URL with original URL in componentDidMount method in ALertsTable, it works. So code is legit.

[stripped down code here](https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-morning-cfbus)

Comment: `Router`, aka `BrowserRouter`, should be ONLY one in an application - not more not less.  Going thru the code you provided, you have it set up just right - one `Router`.  All `Route` and `Link` are inside it. In fact - the content updates whenever you click on your link for me

Comment: Only URL changes, view remains the same. If there's some service endpoint with pagination enabled for demo purposes, we can replace example.com URL with that and see only URL is changing.

Comment: View changes navigating between `home` and `open_alerts` with URL changes. The other part of the code is somewhat untestable sicne it just gets an error for failing a fetch. But even after mocking up the data theer are some issues: some elemnts are missing `key` in `.map`, such as your `paginated_button`, missing `thead` and `tbody` elements and few other small oversights. But the reason, when you click on your page number` why view dosent chnage is because you do NOT have any `Route` that takes such argument. [1/2]

Comment: going into a route `/open_alerts/?page=21` does nothing because there is no nested `Route` that takes it like `<Route path={`${path}/:page_id`}`. All you have is to add `?page={id}` running, but you have nothing that takes it. The only `Route`s you have set up is in `App` that takes paths `/open_alerts` and `/`. Nesting rounting info https://reactrouter.com/web/example/nesting [2/2]

Comment: i will try <Route path={${path}/:page_id} thing. i also thought about this but then I argued myself that path "/open_alert/?page=21" would match "/open_alert/" Route because i have not set the exact attribue in that Route. So it means i was wring?

Comment: what should be my value of path in Route? "<Route path={"/open_alerts/?page"+page_no}> " would give me undefined variable for obvious reasons and  i guess  path={${path}/:page_id}  would not work for query strings.

Comment: when you have a path, lets say, `/home/profile`, the react-router will match the first part `/home`, if it dosent have `exact` set, and will load the component. inside it you may have a new `Switch` that checks for `/profile` and loads the component based on that. In you case you need `/open_alert/:page_id`. the `${path}` is just `/open_alert` aka the current path. The `:page_id` is a parameter. Inside the component, that is loaded via `/open_alert` you need to check if the parameter exist. if not - load this component. if does - load another component passing the parameter

Comment: Its same as in react-router documentation on nested routes about `topic` https://reactrouter.com/web/example/nesting

Comment: i got it about nested routes. but my point is Route with path set to "/open_alert/?:page_id" or even "/open_alert/?page=:page_id" match "/open_alert/?page=4"?

Comment: Path set to `/open_alert/?:page_id` will match `/open_alert/4` or just `/open_alert` since theres a `?` before the parameter. I have not tried with `/open_alert/?page=:page_id`, or similar, so even tho it looks like it could wotk, i can not provide any info if it will work like `/open_alert/page=4` or not, sorry. Altho kinda confused why you want to specify `page=`, its just 1 parameter.